# Can Spyder programmatically open a python file given its absolute path?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using inspect.getfile() to get the python file directory of some class of interest, and then I would ideally like to be able to open it semi-automatically. As it stands, I copy paste the directory into the open window and it takes some navigating.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the file to open _in Spyder_ once you've found the path?

Comment: Yeah, I would like some easy way of going from a directory string to opening the file in spyder. Does that seem unreasonable?

Comment: Not at all - just wanted to be sure before I answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the path to your file, you can use IPython magic command `%edit path` from the console or within a script in the following way:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

path = "C:/path/to/your/file.py"

ipython = get_ipython()

ipython.magic(f"%edit {path}")
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Pretty clever!! I haven't thought about that.